# Tensorflow Hub causes tensorflow logging to duplicate!

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

My Tensorflow logging messages shows twice. After some investigation I
figured out the cause is Tensorflow Hub.

> **Example:**

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub 

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

tf.logging.info("Hello test!")
```

**Output:**

```
INFO:tensorflow:Hello test!
I0523 16:35:51.024926 140735788589952 log.py:13] Hello test!
```

**Desired output:**

```
 INFO:tensorflow:Hello test!
```

> **What I tried:**

I tried to inverse the order of the imports and I ended up with only the second line of output. This is better but I want to know how to get only the first line of the output! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that Tensorflow Hub uses https://abseil.io/docs/python/guides/logging whether as tensorflow uses regular python logging.

Switching the type of logging used by Tensorflow Hub is something to consider. Meanwhile, the issue could be worked around by re-order the import statements:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
tf.logging.info('This is a log')
```